# Can gradle android apk project dependencies another apk project's jar task?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project with two modules:

first one **HostProject**
second one **SubProject**

`LibProject` is a android apk project but has a jar task to make a jar from the code.
jar task:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from 'build/intermediates/classes/debug'
    archiveName 'SubProject.jar'
}
```

In `HostProject` I want to use libproject's code by the jar file. Is there someway easy to add dependency?

**HostProject** build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    ****compile project(':LibProject')****
}
```

---

gradle show error: **resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency**

### can I use the dependencies in **HostProject**'s `build.gradle` without add new task?